# How to get apache airflow to render Hive HQL ${variables} with Jinja

Tags: hive, jinja2, airflow

It seems like this is supported where you pass in a HQL script with ${xxx} vars and it gets preprocessed to convert them to {{xxx}} Jinja-style before the stage that actually does the template rendering to then replace those with values from a user-supplied dictionary. I believe this because there is a function like this in the HiveOperator class:

```
def prepare_template(self):
    if self.hiveconf_jinja_translate:
        self.hql = re.sub(
            "(\$\{([ a-zA-Z0-9_]*)\})", "{{ \g<2> }}", self.hql)
    if self.script_begin_tag and self.script_begin_tag in self.hql:
        self.hql = "\n".join(self.hql.split(self.script_begin_tag)[1:])
```

The problem is I cannot figure out how to trigger this piece of code to get called before the template rendering stage. I have a basic DAG script like this:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.hive_operator import HiveOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

default_args = dict(
    owner='mpetronic',
    depends_on_past=False,
    start_date=datetime(2017, 5, 2),
    verbose=True,
    retries=1,
    retry_delay=timedelta(minutes=5)
    )

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='report',
    schedule_interval='* * * * *',
    user_defined_macros=dict(a=1, b=2),
    default_args=default_args)

hql = open('/home/mpetronic/repos/airflow/resources/hql/report.hql').read()

task = HiveOperator(
    task_id='report_builder',
    hive_cli_conn_id='hive_dv',
    schema='default',
    mapred_job_name='report_builder',
    hiveconf_jinja_translate=True,
    dag=dag,
    hql=hql)
```

I can see that my user_defined_macros dictionary makes it to the code where it gets merged with a global jinja context dictionary that then is applied to my HQL script to render it as a template. However, because my HQL is native HQL, all my variables that I want to update are in the form of ${xxx} and jinja just skips over them. I need airflow to call prepare_template() first but just don't see how to make that happen.

I realize I could just manually alter my HQL ${xxx} to {{xxx}} as that works but that seems like an anti-pattern. I want the script to be able to work natively or via airflow. This is the function, in the TaskInstance class, the does render my manually altered {{xxx}} values:

```
def render_templates(self):
    task = self.task
    jinja_context = self.get_template_context()
    if hasattr(self, 'task') and hasattr(self.task, 'dag'):
        if self.task.dag.user_defined_macros:
            jinja_context.update(
                self.task.dag.user_defined_macros)

    rt = self.task.render_template  # shortcut to method
    for attr in task.__class__.template_fields:
        content = getattr(task, attr)
        if content:
            rendered_content = rt(attr, content, jinja_context)
            setattr(task, attr, rendered_content)
```

Comment: able to get the above working fine in airflow 1.8, the ${xxx} form variables in hql file get replaced with corresponding entries in the user_defined_macros. Did you maybe try adding a logger in the abover stage of the code? In my case am able to see the invocation with corresponding replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my issue. This is the regex used in the noted method:

```
(\$\{([ a-zA-Z0-9_]*)\})
```

It does not account for beeline variables in the form of:

```
${hivevar:var_name}
```

It does not consider a colon in the pattern. That form is the more standard way of defining Hive variables within a namespace using beeline. To make this Jinja substitution work, you have to reference variables in the HQL using just `${var_name}` but you can only define variables in beeline using:

```
set hivevar:var_name=123;
```

I think that Airflow should fully support the `hivevar:var_name` style of namespaced variables when you are running with beeline given beeline is the preferred client to use with Hive.